# How to make connection between two django apps in two different docker containers?

Tags: python, django, docker, rest, docker-compose

I have created two apps 'myapi' and 'minombre' where the 'minombre' will make a simple GET request to 'myapi' and put them in two separate docker containers.After I run 'docker-compose up' the containers run but the api don't pass the data. The views.py of the 'minombre' where the GET request is made is given below:

```
def index(request):
    response = requests.get('http://myapi')
    print(response)
    data = response.json()
    name = data['user']
    message = data['message']

    return HttpResponse('<h2> {} </h2> <br> <h5> {} </h5>'.format(name, message))
```

This is the docker-compose.yml that I have used to get the containers running.

```
version: '3'
services:
  myapi:
    build: ./myapi
    container_name: myapi
   
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
  
  minombre:
    build: ./minombre
    container_name: minombre
   
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

    depends_on:
      - myapi
```

This is the exception:

```
Exception Type: ConnectionError
Exception Value:    
HTTPConnectionPool(host='myapi', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f69b902bbd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!!! I just had to mention hostname in ALLOWED_HOSTS of the **api's** **settings.py** file. Thanks for the help everyone!!!

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1',]
```

Answer (score 2):

If both containers are deployed in same host and want to make API call from "minombre" to "myapi" Django app then you can use below URL in "minombre" view it should work.

```
response = requests.get('http://myapi:8001/')  # where myapi is the container name
```

EDIT

Two Django containers minombre and myapi running on port 8000 and 8001 respectively.

```
(venv) shakeel@my-workstation 20:54:44 ~/workspace $ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
aefa0c5d4bc6        workspace_minombre   "python manage.py ru…"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   minombre
558e22e612f5        workspace_myapi      "python manage.py ru…"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       0.0.0.0:8001->8001/tcp   myapi
(venv) shakeel@my-workstation 20:54:48 ~/workspace $
```

When DEBUG is True and ALLOWED_HOSTS is empty, the host is validated against ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]']. [source][1]

```
(venv) shakeel@my-workstation 20:54:51 ~/workspace $ cat minombre/minombre/settings.py | grep "ALLOWED_HOST"
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
(venv) shakeel@my-workstation 20:55:29 ~/workspace $ curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 05 Nov 2019 20:56:01 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 11

(venv) shakeel@my-workstation 20:56:01 ~/workspace $
```

Now I have added my container name to allowed host

```
(venv) shakeel@my-workstation 21:00:42 ~/workspace $ cat myapi/myapi/settings.py |grep "ALLOWED_HOST"
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myapi', '127.0.0.1',]
```

I have added simple json response to API myapi:8001

```
(venv) shakeel@my-workstation 21:04:57 ~/workspace $ cat myapi/polls/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    responseData = {
        'id': 4,
        'name': 'Test Response',
        'roles' : ['Admin','User']
    }

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(responseData))

(venv) shakeel@my-workstation 21:05:02 ~/workspace $
(venv) shakeel@my-workstation 21:05:04 ~/workspace $
```

And now we are calling API myapi:8001 under minombre:8000's view

```
(venv) shakeel@my-workstation 21:05:04 ~/workspace $ cat minombre/polls/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    response = requests.get('http://myapi:8001/polls/')
    data = response.json()
    return HttpResponse(data)
(venv) shakeel@my-workstation 21:05:14 ~/workspace $
```

Now when you call minombre API success response.

```
(venv) shakeel@my-workstation 21:05:14 ~/workspace $ curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 05 Nov 2019 20:41:10 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 11

(venv) shakeel@my-workstation 21:05:14 ~/workspace $
```

But with settings `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myapi', '127.0.0.1',]` we cannot access from container, however you can still connect from host machine.

```
(venv) shakeel@my-workstation 21:06:19 ~/workspace $ curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8001/polls/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 05 Nov 2019 21:06:31 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 62

(venv) shakeel@my-workstation 21:07:15 ~/workspace $ 
(venv) shakeel@my-workstation 21:08:15 ~/workspace $ cat myapi/myapi/settings.py |grep "ALLOWED_HOST"
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myapi', '127.0.0.1',]
(venv) shakeel@my-workstation 21:08:35 ~/workspace $ sudo docker exec -it minombre bash
root@aefa0c5d4bc6:/code# curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8001/polls/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8001: Connection refused
root@aefa0c5d4bc6:/code#
```

Comment: myapi is not the container name

Comment: I tried this long ago. Still doesn't work. When I enter a container using exec and ping the other one, it works just fine. But requests.get does not

Comment: @LinPy please find my edit where I see myapi as container name which I was referring too.

Comment: @HasibA., please let me know if my explanation(EDIT section) was helpful to properly connect two APIs internally and also accept if you find it was relevant to your expected answer.

Comment: I had solved it a while ago and mentioned it as an answer. Your suggestion to mention the port was helpful but my problem was, I forgot to put 127.0.0.1 inside the api's ALLOWED_HOSTS

Answer (score -1):

Here is solution you just need two apps to make part of the same network.

Below is a docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '3'
 networks:
   main:

services:
 myapi:

 build: ./myapi
 container_name: myapi
 ports:
   - "8001:8001"
  networks:
   - main
 command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001

minombre:

 build: ./minombre
 container_name: minombre
 ports:
  - "8000:8000"
  networks:
  - main
 command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
 depends_on:
   - myapi
```

Now they will be part of same network so you can easily you docker DNS to hit APIs.

Comment: Docker Compose [creates a `default` network for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and this manual setup isn't necessary.