# Accessing apps living in different Docker containers being parts of different docker-compose services

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two django apps. Both are run as part of two different docker-compose files.

App 1 docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
  django:
    build: .
    command: ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
    ports:
      - "8013:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
```

App 2 docker-compose.yml file

```
services:
    django:
        build: .
        container_name: "web"
        command: ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
        ports:
          - "8003:8000"
        volumes:
          - ./:/app
        depends_on:
          - db
```

So basically, my goal is to call App 2's django endpoint from App 1. To do this, in app 1's code, I utilize url `http://web:8003/app2_endpoint`

Also, I have `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']` in both projects

Yet, I end up with `Max retries exceeded` error.
I also came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705959/how-to-make-connection-between-two-django-apps-in-two-different-docker-container), but I failed to figure out the solution for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify custom docker network in your compose file, each compose file would create a separated network for itself. So basically your containers in separated compose can't see each other

The solution can be using same docker network in compose files. Sth like:

```yaml
services:
...

networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: YOUR_DOCKER_NETWORK
```

And add it in another compose too

This tells compose to use an external docker network as default, named `YOUR_DOCKER_NETWORK`

Note that you should create this network by yourself, because it's external:

```
docker network create YOUR_DOCKER_NETWORK
```

You can also use custom networks

Docs in https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/